# Yield current fiber until FD has some data

Tags: crystal-lang, fibers

In a crystal program that's using a C library via FFI, I have code that blocks when reading from a file descriptor. How can I yield the fiber until that file descriptor has some data?

e.g. the current code is something like:

```
f = File.open("/some/socket/or/pipe/like/object")
Iterator.of do
  data = Pointer(LibFoo::Data).malloc
  # yield_until_fd_has_data f.fd
  LibFoo.read f.fd, data
  data.value
end
```

Where `LibFoo.read` blocks until the socket/pipe-like object has some data. What do I use in place of `yield_until_fd_has_data`?

Answer (score 0):

One way that I've found so far is to subclass `IO::FileDescriptor` and override the `resume_read` method. Then use `Crystal::EventLoop.create_fd_read_event(my_subclass).add`, which will then cause the overridden `resume_read` method to be called when the FD is ready for reading.

However this seems somewhat dependent on the internals, so could break in the future. For now I'm using this, but I'd love to see an official solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `poll` with zero timeout to get the ready-state of the file descriptor. You'll need to write the C bindings for this function yourself, it's not available in the stdlib.

And then it's just something like

```
while LibC.poll(fd_struct, 1, 0) == 0
   Fiber.yield
end
```